# Google Sheet Script : Is there a way to display a message without stop the script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, settimeout, alert, utilities

Simple question :  Is there a way to display a message without stop the script ?

`Alert()` stop the script.

`setTimeOut` seems be usefull but it's not available and  `Utilities.sleep()` seems not working that way.

Someone can help me?

Thank's you

Comment: There's Spreadsheet.toast()  and modeless dialog()

Answer (score 0):

`modeless dialog()` was exactly What I need.

Thank's  Cooper